# Regular expression fails on unicode

Tags: php, regex, unicode

I'm trying to find the string "C#" in a text using php and reg exp.

I'm using

```
\bc\x{0023}\b
```

But doesn't work at all.

```
\bc\x{0023}
```

works but that's not a solution for me

Any clue ?

Comment: unicode works but the \b after the unicode doesnt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the escape sequence `\b` means a word boundary. Word is defined according to the PHP manual as:
"*A "word" character is any letter or digit or the underscore character, that is, any character which can be part of a Perl "word".*".

Word boundary means the boundary between a word and a nonword. In otherwords, a between a character that is a word character and character is a not a word character. The problem is that `#` is not a word character. Thus, unless `#` is followed by a word character, `#\b` will never match.

Perhaps you should define more clearly using character classes what you want. For example `/\bc#(?![a-z])/i` (that is, C# that is not followed by a-z character range)

Comment: I was using this expression before I realised that It failed with #, i use for example \bjava\b to find java,java and java but not javabean